# How to remove links on the footer in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

The links I am trying to remove are in yellow. I have tried the links.phtml file and when I remove it or alter it the links under the account tab will not pop up when the account link is clicked. I am using magento 1.9 and the included template that come with the install. Does anyone know how to remove the bottom ones and it not effect the top links.[image]

Comment: Hi there , there may be chances that this footer is rendered from the CMS , did u try debugging there in admin side CMS pages ?Thanks.

Comment: Yes and I found the file that removes them but it is removing the top links as well even though the do not appear to be sharing the same block name or CMS file. I'm at a loss of what would cause it to do that and I think I am just over looking something, but don't know where to begin to look.

Comment: Ah yes, this is default Magento RWD theme, the same as the top.links in the header but If I remember correctly you had to remove them all independently through XML. I also remember struggling a lot with keeping these columns size properly when going from desktop to mobile. Are you still stuck on this issue? The theme I was working on at the time is on my backup drive at home. Also based on RWD, same problem so I can send you the code that made me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Those links aren't hardcoded or coming from CMS either, they are added dynamically via layout XML files. Example from `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml`:

```xml
<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
</reference>
```

The easiest way to remove them is via your own layout XML file from your custom theme like so:

```xml
<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /></action>
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" /></action>
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" /></action>
</reference>
```